# Why is this Angular expression in an ng-class inside an ng-repeat always treated as true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I can't get my head around this.

I am displaying a collection of objects with `ng-repeat`, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objs">{{obj | json}}</div>
```

Then, I want to apply the class `current` to one of these `<div>` elements based on whether the object it represented is the “current object”; i.e., in practice, whether `obj` points to the same thing as another scope variable `current`.

I tried this:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objs" ng-class="{current: 'obj == current'}">{{obj | json}}, current: {{obj == current}}</div>
```

The funny thing is: the expression `obj == current` is correctly evaluated in the body of the div, and is initially false for all of them, when the value of `current` in the scope is `null`. But the class is applied to all of them nevertheless, although it is supposed to depend on the exact same expression.

Whenever I change the value of `current` to point to another object, the text inside the div updates accordingly, and changes to `true`, but the class always stays applied.

What am I missing here? Why is the class applied even if the expression yields `false`?

To play with it: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8qUU/).

Comment: Remove the quotes around the condition (ng-class="{current: obj == current}")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes are causing this to fail. It should be changed to:

```
ng-class="{'current': obj == current}"
```

Edited your JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qXgJm/1/

The quotes were causing it to always return true, because the string was truthy

Example:
This would evaluate to true, and log the '!!!!'

```
if ("hello world") {
  console.log('!!!!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the expression without `'` in your ng-class.

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objs" ng-class="{current: obj == current}">{{obj | json}}, current: {{obj == current}}</div>
```

Just like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jackypan1989/vY939/)